# Banking open data from Credit Agricole?

Tags: data-request, finance

A colleague told me that the Credit Agricole in France as published a dataset of banking transactions as part of their Open Data initiative.

I tried to research it on different sites in France but I couldn't find it.  Anyone has heard / found it  yet?

I would be keen to have a look at it and see what sort of analytics it is possible to do with it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the Crédit Agricole API, which has a page [here](https://www.creditagricolestore.fr/castore-data-provider/docs/V1/rest.html). As far as I can tell, it's designed for app designers so each account would require individual authentication. Maybe

There are tons of news stories about it, check out examples [here](http://blogs.forrester.com/jennifer_belissent_phd/13-03-28-one_small_step_for_credit_agricole_one_giant_leap_for_the_data_economy), [here](http://www.bankinnovation.net/2013/02/credit-agricole-opens-its-api-and-good-things-happen/) or [here](http://www.americanbanker.com/magazine/123_8/open-api-for-bank-apps-can-credit-agricoles-model-work-1060535-1.html).